# How to sound enthusiastic about the job role over telephonic interview

Tags: interviewing, telecommute

I am about to have a telephonic interview with a company, but i had a previous interview with some other company which turned me down, the reason was

> We didn't see him as a long term, like to say he sounded that he ws in for a contract or short term

This was the feedback i got from recruiter from them,another face 2 face interview feedback was similar (IMO) as follow

> My last interview feedback was long through a recruiter and it says the following
>   He - Was the strongest of the three (technically speaking) – He clearly knows his stuff in terms of coding (across a variety of platforms) – but his interview answers were far too meandering and vague for us to be able to take things forward with him. He also didn’t seem to have really engaged with what the organisation is before coming in for interview. Additionally, while we have no doubt he could perform a support role admirably as part of a technical/development team – we weren’t convinced that he could take the initiative at times – which is crucial for this role as it develops over the next 12 months. While there is a lot of strategic support/consultation within the team (hence us not advertising for a head of digital) we do need someone who can ‘join the dots’ and actually see creative ways to realise our projects. He came across as being better suited to a role where there is a clear/responsible Development Lead in charge.

So how can i sound more enthusiastic about the role on the phone?

Comment: Do you agree with their feedback and ask how to change, or do you disagree and ask how to come across better? Do you know what you really want in a job and a company, and how well did these fit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually taught this in a class.

If you ever get the chance to see voice actors recording a session, they are never sitting.  They are standing and going through all the same motions as if they were acting on stage, including hand gestures, movements, arm waiving, the works.

The same thing holds true for a voice interview:

This is what I taught in my class.

1. Stand, don't sit.
2. Smile.  Whether or not you are smiling comes across in your voice.
3. Be animated.  Walk around the room, make the same gestures that you would make if you were in an in person interview
4. Pysch yourself up.  No actor goes in cold, and neither should you.  Take a few minutes before the phone interview to think of all the reasons you want to work there.
5. Be sincere and complete in your answers.  Again, everything is going to come through in your voice.  They WILL pick up on it more during a voice interview as there is not the distraction of looking at you
6. Good posture and body language.  What?  for a phone interview?  Yes!  Again, it comes through in your voice.

These are a few basic tips that can make your interviews go much better.  In addition to my other activities, I sing.  An old music teacher of mine admonished us for leaning forward on our seats like we were sitting on the toilet.   "It sounds like what it looks like", he said.

Take this advice, it **will** help

Answer (score 5):

The feedback you received should be considered a gift.

Seriously,  it is uncommon to ever be told the reasons for rejection. Many folks are blindsided by a rejection and never understand what was wrong. In your case feedback is clear and generously shows where you need work, you should take it as a roadmap for how to improve your future interviews.

The difficult thing for you will be TO ACTUALLY BE enthusiastic about the job. You can't merely "sound" enthusiastic or "appear" enthusiastic as though you are acting. Acting, unless you happen to be an actor, will come off as inauthentic and nothing will turn interviewers off faster than someone who isn't fully genuine.

Technical competency is only one part of the consideration that hiring managers need for a decision. They also try to assess how the candidate will work with the team and what the organization needs in terms of people who are able to take initiative and leadership.

The best thing you can do us to practice interviewing with a trusted colleague or mentor who can help you to find find your voice and give you advice on communication.